# Antd 3.26 form validation messages are not rerendering with new value when state/props are changing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, antd

I have a React app that uses Antd 3.26 (I cannot migrate it to the new version). In this App I have a simple translation functionality. The user can change the language via select, and the UI is updated with labels that are fetched from json file. And here I've encounter this problem:

All the labels are updated to the new language except for the **validation messages** when the form is submitted. I believe it's the problem with the label component not being rerendered, but I have no clue how I can workaround or fix it.

Here is the code from the test app that I made for this question to illustrate my problem:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { Form, Input, Button } from 'antd';

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    validationNameMessage: "Please input your name",
    validationPasswordMessage: "Please input your password",
  }


  onBtnClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.form.validateFieldsAndScroll((err, values) => {
      // here is a simulated "request" to my backend server to get translation
      setTimeout(() => this.setState({ validationNameMessage: "Podaj nazwe", validationPasswordMessage: "Podaj haslo" }), 2000)
    });
  }
  render() {
    const { getFieldDecorator } = this.props.form;

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="form-container">
          <Form name="test-form">
            <Form.Item label="Name">
              {getFieldDecorator("name", {
                rules: [
                  {
                    required: true,
                    message: this.state.validationNameMessage
                  }
                ]
              })(<Input />)}
            </Form.Item>
            <Form.Item style={{ marginTop: 12 }} label="Password">
              {getFieldDecorator("password", {
                rules: [
                  {
                    required: true,
                    message: this.state.validationPasswordMessage
                  }
                ]
              })(<Input />)}
            </Form.Item>
            <Form.Item>
              <Button onClick={this.onBtnClick} style={{ marginTop: 12 }} type="primary" htmlType="submit">
                Submit
              </Button>
            </Form.Item>
          </Form>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Form.create({ name: 'test-form' })(App);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with the example you provided is that the non-translated validations are already rendered before the translations arrive, and hence, will show only if you re-trigger the validation following the translations arrival.

One possible solution will be to use the `setFields` method from the [Form API](https://3x.ant.design/components/form/#Form.create(options)). You can trigger the translated validations right after you set them on the state, like this:

```
 this.setState(
          {
            validationNameMessage: "Podaj nazwe",
            validationPasswordMessage: "Podaj haslo"
          },
          //callback that triggers after the state has been updated
          () => {
            this.props.form.setFields({
              name: {
                value: values.name,
                errors: [
                  // only show the validation error if there is no value in the field
                  ...(values.name
                    ? []
                    : [new Error(this.state.validationNameMessage)])
                ]
              },
              password: {
                value: values.password,
                errors: [
                  ...(values.name
                    ? []
                    : [new Error(this.state.validationPasswordMessage)])
                ]
              }
            });
          }
        );
```

This will still flash the none-translated validations for a short time (2 seconds in your example) but will switch to the translated validations as soon as they arrive.

[Here is a sandbox demonstrating the suggested solution with the example you provided](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-q-63526592-vx9gy?file=/src/App.js:494-1239).